# Differential Equation For Air Remaining During a SCUBA Dive Ascent

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the theoretical situation of being a SCUBA diver doing an emergency ascent, I'm trying to find how much air you'd have to blow out at a constant rate to not have any air when you reach the surface.

The differential equation I've managed to find is$$\frac{da}{dt}=ka-f$$
Where $k$ is dependant on the fluid and rate of ascent, $f$ is the constant amount of air you blow out, and $a$ is the volume of air.

For a 1-second ascent $f$ is about $1.38677$ and for any length ascent to get the same amount of air this is half of that value, about $.69314$. These were found with the equation $$a_c=2^{dt}a_p-fdt$$ and was put into python

Any help solving this would be much appreciated

Comment: What are $a_c$ and $a_p$? What is $dt$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the differential equation explicitly using the integration factor. The solution is

$$ a(t) = \frac{f}{k} + ce^{kt} $$

where $c$ is some constant depending on the initial condition. If the initial air is $a(0)=a_0$, this further reduces to

$$ a(t) = \frac{f}{k} + \left(a_0 - \frac{f}{k}\right)e^{kt} $$

If you know the time it takes for there to be no air left, you can solve for $f$ from the above expression.